# How to run with the Android Test Orchestrator from Android Studio IDE instead of command line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-test-orchestrator

I would like my tests to use the [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) when I run from Android Studio but the documentation only describes [running it from the command line](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator):

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

I prefer to run from Android Studio where I can simply press the play button next to a test and it runs just that test.  I believe Android Studio generates what it calls a "Run/Debug Configuration" for the test.  I believe a Debug Configuration is needed in order to set breakpoints in the test code and/or breakpoints for the code associated with the system under test--I assume breakpoints don't work when you run from the command line.

But does the Run/Debug Configuration employ the Android Test Orchestrator?  From my testing it does not appear to because my app only asks for permissions on a wiped emulator.  I believe the emulator is retaining granted permissions across runs which the Android Test Orchestrator is not supposed to do.

I looked at the Run/Debug Configuration Android Studio generated when I tapped the play button.  It seems like it's using the Android Test Orchestrator because the configuration panel "General" shows the following options:

Instrumentation class: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Instrumentation arguments: clearPackageData true

On the configuration panel "Miscellaneous" I found under "Installation Options" the option "Skip installation if APK has not changed".  It was selected by default.  I tried unselecting it but that didn't clear the permissions on my emulator.

How do I make Android Studio's Run/Debug Configuration employ the Android Test Orchestrator?

I looked for others who've asked this question but couldn't find this specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the current [Android Developer AndroidJUnitRunner docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#ato-studio) the steps to making Android Studio's test play buttons use Android Test Orchestrator work for me i.e. add the lines of code to your build config.